# The verb "to participate" for an object

Tags: word-usage

Can the verb "to participate" be used for an object (and not a person)? For example: "This equipment will participate in a qualification test." Is this correct?

Comment: Note, first of all, that the preposition _in_ is required with _participate_, which can't have an object by itself. It's "to participate in" that you're asking about. Second, any thing that is sufficiently anthropomorphized can act like an agent, and _participate in_ needs an agent subject. _Ol' Betsy here has partipated in a lot of steam rallies_ is perfectly all right, though _participate in_ falutes a bit too high; _taken part in_ might be a better phrase.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really work in that context.

You'd be better using something like:

> This equipment will ***feature***...

Answer (score 1):

Not grammatically wrong, but sounds unusual. "this equipment **is undergoing** a qualification test" sounds like a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

[Participate :](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/participate) usually  refer to people or entities like, a company, a state or an organization:

> - to take part or have a share, as with others (usu. fol. by in): to participate in profits; to participate in a conversation.

In the context you are suggesting,  *be subjected to or go through* can be used to suggest the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
Feature
```

As participate sounds a bit odd: I'd say it was more for people.

As an aside, you could use **feature** or **undergo** in this context, however they would grant the sentence different meanings: feature would imply that the object is going to just be in the test, perhaps helping, whereas undergo would suggest that it is having the test done to it.

As previously suggested by John Lawler the object in question could be sufficiently *anthropomorphised* such that **participate in** would make sense, as in the sentence he suggested